# High pressure collapsing time of Water, Air or any medium by size and speed of waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics, explosions

Explosion in water ( air ) creates high pressure, and expands water ( air ), and after that it collapses back.

[image]

How to calculate time or speed of collapsing, if wave propagation speed of water or air and diameter of explosion are known ?

Comment: I have a physics friend who has done this calculation countless times. contact me through my webpage at www.nielsenkillowatt.com if you want to get in touch with him. -Niels

Comment: Thank you, I will get in touch with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rayleigh-Plesset equation models the bubble dynamics under the assumption of the bubble being spherical in an incompressible liquid. The [Wikipedia page of the derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Plesset_equation) nicely expands that from the book [*Brennen, Christopher E. (1995). Cavitation and Bubble Dynamics. Oxford University Press. ISBN 978-0-19-509409-1.*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/36721045_Cavitation_and_Bubble_Dynamics) This book has [a corrected edition on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107644763).

The Wikipedia page [Cavitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation) as well as its See Also section of links have a comprehensive treatment on this topic.